# Azure SQL DB and Power Apps/Power Automate Private Connectivity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, powerapps, power-automate

I have created an Azure SQL DB, with the public access off, and private endpoint created for private connectivity.

I am trying to access the Azure SQL DB via Power Apps and Power Automate, but each time, it fails to connect and asks me to whitelist the 'public' ip in the Azure SQL DB firewall. I am not fond of this approach of whitelisting public IPs.

Is there any other way to connect Azure SQL DB from Power Apps privately?

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Comment: Can you check [this](https://i.imgur.com/gUVevfG.png) once it may work to add IP address.

Comment: adding the IP address will make it go via the public route, right? Also the IP for the Power Automate service might change daily not making it feasible to whitelist so many IPs.

Comment: IP for the power automation service means you are asking about the latest DLP policy issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/defender-for-cloud/sql-azure-vulnerability-assessment-rules.md) SQL database don't grant access more than 255 IP address. To connect Azure SQL database with Power Apps by using private endpoint, disable public access in SQL server networking settings.

[image]

Create virtual network and add the required Ip address of PowerApps to the subnet

[image]

Create private endpoint for azure sql server with created vnet and subnet and approve it.

[image]

Try to connect database with PowerApps by entering the required details of server. By disabling public access, you won't get notification of whitelisting the IP address.
For more information you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-sql-portal).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add the required Ip address of PowerApps to the subnet?"